# returning and receiving methods

Tags: java, methods

I'm a beginner coder and I'm trying to achieve the output at the bottom by calling different methods in my main method but I keep getting errors. Can somebody please point me in the right direction. Not sure if I need to list the parameters inside the calling methods in the main header or not.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CityOrozcoB52 
{ // begin class
  private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  { // begin main method

    String city, state;
    float cityPopulation, statePopulation;



    cityName();
    stateName();
    cityPopulation(city);
    statePopulation(state);
    cityPercState(cityPopulation, statePopulation);
    displayCityStateStats(cityName, stateName, cityPopulation, statePopulation, cityPercState);



 } // end main method

  public static String cityName()
  {
    String city = "";
    System.out.printf("What is the name of your city:");
     city = input.nextLine();

     return city;
  }

  public static String stateName()
  {
    String state = "";
    System.out.printf("What is the name of your state:");
    state = input.nextLine();

    return state;
  }

  public static float cityPopulation(String city)
  {
    float cityPopulation = 0;
    System.out.printf("what is the population of %s:\n", city);
    cityPopulation = input.nextFloat();

    return cityPopulation; 
  }
  public static float statePopulation(String state);
  {
    float statePopulation = 0;
    System.out.printf("what is the population of %s:", state);
    statePopulation = input.nextFloat();

    return statePopulation;
  }

  public static float cityPercState(float cityPopulation, float statePopulation)
  {
   float cityStatePercentage = (cityPopulation / statePopulation) * 100; 
  }

  public static void displayCityStateStats(String cityName, String stateName, float cityPopulation, float statePopulation, 
                                      float cityPercState)
  {
   System.out.printf("POPULATION STATISTICS\n\n"
                    + "City: %s"
                    + "State: %s"
                    + "City Population: %f"
                    + "State Population: %f"
                    + "City to State Population: %.2f%%", cityName, stateName, cityPopulation, statePopulation, 
                                                          cityPercState);

  }
} // ends CityOrozcoLE52
```

Comment: Would help if you put a tag for the language you are using, as well as gave examples of the type of errors you are experiencing.  As your question stands its not easy for the community to provide you assistance.

Comment: the language is java & these are my errors.   6 errors found:
File: E:\New Folder\CityOrozcoB52.java  [line: 27]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable cityName
  location: class CityOrozcoB52
File: E:\New Folder\CityOrozcoB52.java  [line: 27]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable stateName
  location: class CityOrozcoB52
File: E:\New Folder\CityOrozcoB52.java  [line: 27]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable cityPercState
  location: class CityOrozcoB52

Answer (score 3):

You declared the variables in your main method, but you didn't initialize them. Since you created methods with return types and intend to return values such as the name of a city, you must catch the values being returned by each method using the variables you have declared.

For example, in **main**:

```
city = cityName();
```

Also, it seems that your program intends to model data/ information about a city. You are missing a **constructor** for your class. Have you learned about creating classes/objects? If not, I suggest doing so. This program would be a lot cleaner and more organized if programmed using constructors, setters, and getters (accessor and mutator methods).

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing what errors you are getting this is a little tricky, but I think you are having trouble with the scope of your variables.  Like in the following calls from your main() method:

```
cityName();
stateName();
cityPopulation(city);
statePopulation(state);
cityPercState(cityPopulation, statePopulation);
displayCityStateStats(cityName, stateName, cityPopulation, statePopulation, cityPercState);
```

you are not "catching" the returned values from cityName() or any of the other functions.  The following would most likely work:

```
float cityPercState;
city = cityName();
state = stateName();
cityPopulation = cityPopulation(city);
statePopulation = statePopulation(state);
cityPercState = cityPercState(cityPopulation, statePopulation);
displayCityStateStats(city, state, cityPopulation, statePopulation, cityPercState);
```

So whenever you have a function that returns a value, if you want to access the returned value you need to store it in a variable as I have shown.  Variables you use inside methods are not available in your other methods unless you declare them just inside the class, like your input variable.

Comment: the 6 errors were all "cannot find symbol" with one saying missing method body or declare abstract

Comment: What java compiler/IDE are you using?  From those errors it looks like you are definitely not using your variable right.